# Error Unknown while consuming message on Kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

Producer is a Spring Boot application. using kafka spring version 2.0.0
Consumer is a node service with kafka client version ^5.0.0
Kafka version is 1.1.0

Consumer is getting an error unknown. the complete error stack trace is as follows:

```
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:  Error: Unknown
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at events.push (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/protocol/protocol.js:267:25)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at /var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3883:24
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at replenish (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1014:17)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at /var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1019:9
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at eachOfLimit (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1044:24)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at /var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1049:16
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at _parallel (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3882:5)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at Object.series (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4738:5)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at _decodeFetchResponse (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/protocol/protocol.js:244:9)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at /var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/protocol/protocol.js:199:12
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at KafkaClient.Client.invokeResponseCallback (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/baseClient.js:589:18)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at KafkaClient.Client.handleReceivedData (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/baseClient.js:569:10)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at KafkaClient.handleReceivedData (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:1378:48)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/digital-reminder/releases/source/20230914165222/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:797:10)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
ERR! 2023-09-14 16:57:01 [9.754] [65] Kafka consumer listeners:      at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

The services is working fine on on nonprod servers, where kafka version is 3.2.3

Comment: Seems like a version compatibility issue. Note that kafka-node seems old and unmaintained, I wouldn't recommend it. Consider using KafkaJS to avoid running into such issues.

Comment: @StéphaneD. Not sure that is a good suggestion either https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/1603